# Does NVARCHAR(MAX) consume more storage (physical size) than NVARCHAR(N)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, size, nvarchar

In SQL Server, if you create a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, and populate only 128 characters inside - does it consume more storage than if you'd create it as `NVARCHAR(128)` - or is it the same size?

Comment: When the value is stored in-row, the space will be the same. The MAX type will be more if it needs to be stored out-of-row due to other columns in the row/page. In addition to storage, consider SQL Server will need to account for possibly memory for MAX types in query plans so don't use varchar(MAX) unless you need more than 4000 characters.

Comment: To add on to @DanGuzman's comment, I consider column data type widths as a type of constraint. If the application you're writing is expecting nothing longer than (in your example) 128 characters, make it an `nvarchar(128)` regardless of whether an `nvarchar(max)` would store those same characters in an equivalent amount of storage.

Answer (score 6):

I made a small experiment, use the following code to create 2 tables and populate it with equally random 128 characters:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTextFix (
    [val] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTextMax (
    [val] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0
WHILE (@COUNT <= 100000)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(128) = CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(128)) + '-' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(128)) + '-' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(128)) + '-' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(128))
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTextFix ([val]) VALUES (@VAL)
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTextMax ([val]) VALUES (@VAL)
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
END
```

And now - we'll use the "Disk Usage by Table" to check the actual size of the tables:

[image]

As you can see, even though one table has a `NVARCHAR(128)` and the other has `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data types - if we only populate the 128 characters - both tables are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Storage may be same . You need to consider the following

1. MAX will store data in out of row in LOB allocation
2. When you use MAX, and run a query ,optimizer may grant unnecessary more memory